# Why is 'ros::Publisher': no appropriate default constructor available?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to send some IMU-data form my application (vb.net) to Ros on another pc.
Therefore I use [rosserial_windows](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_windows).
In my application you can choose which data you want to send.
The best way is to build a dll. So I can publish the data I wish to.
Unfortunately I get two errors with ros::Publisher. Here is piece of my code:

```
class Connect2ROS {
public:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    powerball_msgs::ExtPoseInput extPoseInput_msg;
    //ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", extPoseInput_msg);
    ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub ;//
    char *ros_master;
    Connect2ROS() {//here an error appears C2512 'ros::Publisher': no appropriate default constructor avialable
        ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg);
    }

    void InitRosPublish(char *ros_master, std::string topic) { 
        this->ros_master = ros_master;
        printf("Connecting to server at %s\n", ros_master);
        nh.initNode(ros_master);
        printf("Advertising cmd_vel message\n");
        this->cmd_vel_pub = this->nh.advertise< powerball_msgs::ExtPoseInput>("cmd_vel", 1);
//here an error appears C2275 'powerball_msgs::ExtPoseInput':illegal use of this type in expression
        //ros::Publisher cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg);
        /*this->cmd_vel_pub = cmd_vel_pub;*/
        nh.advertise(this->cmd_vel_pub);
    }
    void PublishImuData_Rotation(double rel_vx, double rel_vy, double rel_vz, double x, double y, double z){...}
};
```

What is wrong?  The error appears also when I use e.g. geometry_msgs::Twist as a message.
I didn't find any help in the internet. I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267420/why-is-%27ros::publisher%27:-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available-?/) by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create you Publisher instance in the constructor using : Operator

```
Connect2ROS() :
cmd_vel_pub("cmd_vel", &extPoseInput_msg)
{
// Rest of constructor
```

It's a c++ issue, See member initializer lists For more information:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChrisBecken](https://answers.ros.org/users/29936/chrisbecken/) on 2017-07-27**:
Thank you very much Wolf!! It works.